# jQuery method css not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am preparing for MS exam 70-480 and practicing JavaScript - made an test example with different variations of `.click` events, but it none are working  (buttons are not applying styles not at all).

What is missing/wrong is this code?
https://jsfiddle.net/svguetq7/

```
 // part of code
 $("#btn3").click(function(){
   $("article:first-of-type") .css("background-color", "blue");
 });
```

**Update**

Embaring moment - all buttons had identical IDs, so that was a problem too. Message to others - please check your code extra one more time before asking something to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Add the html. I bet you are missing a # or a . before article...

Comment: @Juan - can you update that example and post link? Because i did not understand clearly where you minded to put 'html'.

Comment: Inspect the page and check the console. Check the error there.

Comment: Great - missing jQuery. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have not included jQuery in the fiddle. Second, you are using the selector in a wrong way. If you need to select the first,second,third elements then use eq() function of jQuery. Sample code:

```
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("section article:eq(0)").css("background-color", "red");
  });
```

Demo for the first element:
https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/svguetq7/8/

Comment: Yes - @Cons7an7ine mentioned about jQuery in comment. Thank you too.